# How to send data from avr micro-controller to website

Tags: web-services, microcontroller, avr

I want to build a device . There will be 2 switches in this device . One is labeled "Satisfied" and another is labeled "UNSATISFIED" . Based on this , two flag(0 or 1) will be send to a particular website .

How can I build this device with AVR micro-controller ? Can You please tell the name of module which is capable of sending data from AVR to website ?

I have searched a lot in INTERNET but have not got any useful resources . Can you please help me by providing any specific link ? I have done some project of AVR and I am novice in the world of micro-controller .

Thanks for co-operation .

Answer (score 0):

Atmel has an Application Note for a Web Server.
**AVR460: Embedded Web Server** 
It's probably over-kill for what you want to do.
Atmel sells a Web Server board for this Application Note.